# Error in assign(name, value, envir = attr(static, ".env")) : use of NULL environment is defunct

Tags: r, environments

I got the following error:

```
Error in assign(name, value, envir = attr(static, ".env")) : use of NULL environment is defunct
```

while running such code

```
location<-strona %>%
html_nodes(".text-nowrap.hidden-xs") %>%
html_text()
```

Do you have understanding how fix this error, so that environment is not NULL environment anymore?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem that has just started to appear on several r scripts that parse websites. There was an update to the package 'selectr' recently. I reverted back to version 0.3-2 of selectr and the problem disappeared.

Comment: What I observed is that my code run successfully with every first run in given session. Once I would like to execute the code again, error pops up.

Comment: what version of selectr are you using? I checked my code again with selectr version 0.4 and the error message happens at different points in the code.

Comment: It does not have to be associated with selectr, in my code I am using multiple packages, namely:
`"rvest",
"stringr",
"tidyr",
"XML",
"xml2",
"foreach",
"rJava",
"xlsx",
"httr",
"devtools",
"rpremraj/mailR",
"RSelenium",
"caTools"`.
I suspect that `rvest` or `stringr` are causing the error, but I am not sure.

Comment: my code was only using rvest. rvest also loads stringr. A new version of stringr was released a few days ago. Since the update my code had issues. Try downgrading to version 0.3-2 and see if the problem is still there

Comment: Most likely it will work, but it was important for me during development. Since code is ready, I run it as self executible file (like .exe file), so it does not bother me anymore